# conditional widget title

Tags: widgets, title

I have a conditional tag that looks something like this:

```
if(is_category(3)) {
// do this

} else {

// do that

}
```

I would like to change the widget title when the condition is true. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go on here!

I'd suggest registering 2 different sidebars - one for the category 3 posts and one for the rest.

Then you can add you widgets and modify them as required.